# NHibernate Search and Lucene Exception

Tags: lucene.net, nhibernate-search

Got error message when one application is using Lucene index exclusively.

Unhandled Exception: NHibernate.Search.Impl.SearchException: Unable to open IndexWriter for *My namespace* ---> Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock *My Index Path*\write.lock

I am just wandering if any of you experienced same problem before?

Answer (score 2):

You probably crashed while the IndexWriter was opened, and the write.lock file was left in the index directory. This file is used by the [SimpleFSLockFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/SimpleFSLockFactory.html) to make sure there is a single IndexWriter opened against a filesystem index at any given time.

Go into your index directory, and delete the write.lock file if NHibernate doesnt deal with it automatically.

Comment: When I saw the exception, the write.lock was not found in the index directory at all.

Comment: Then I guess NHibernate probably deals with it on its own, by unlocking the Directory when it hits the exception. It would be great to have a Nhibernate expert confirm this.

Comment: My experience is that it doesn't remove it automatically. I'm guessing that you try to index from multiple threads in parallell which isn't allowed.